# How setup python path in my ide to recognize QGIS API

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij with python plugin. Classpath for python contains `$QGIS/apps/qgis/python` but my ide not recognize eg. QgsVectorLayer. Any additional entry is required?

Comment: what's the result typing "qgis" in the qgis python console? It should point the the qgis python modules path that have to be the same added to the python path.

Comment: qgis

<module 'qgis' from 'C:/DevEnv/Qgis/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\__init__.pyc'>

Comment: check the $QGIS value, should be "C:/DevEnv/Qgis"